# Frequency plot using dots instead of bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dot-plot

I'm trying to create the chart in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703938/how-to-create-a-dot-plot-in-matplotlib-not-a-scatter-plot), using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707027/3225420).  I'm open to any solution that works.

Visual borrowed from original question:
[image]

Difference from that question is I've already calculated my bins and frequency values so I don't use `numpy` or `matplotlib` to do so.

Here's my sample data, I refer to it as `df_fd` in my sample code below:

```
     low_bin   high_bin  frequency
0  13.142857  18.857143          3
1  18.857143  24.571429          5
2  24.571429  30.285714          8
3  30.285714  36.000000          8
4  36.000000  41.714286          7
5  41.714286  47.428571          7
6  47.428571  53.142857          1
7  53.142857  58.857143          1
```

Based off the cited question here's my code (`df_fd` is the `DataFrame` above):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df_fd.low_bin, df_fd.frequency, width= df_fd.high_bin-df_fd.low_bin)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(bins, df_fd['frequency'])
Y = Y.astype(np.float)
Y[Y>df_fd['frequency']] = np.nan
plt.scatter(X,Y)
```

This `Y[Y>df_fd['frequency']] = np.nan` statement is what fails and I don't know how to get around it. I understand what it's trying to do and the best guess I have is somehow mapping the matrix index to the DataFrame index would help, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hacky solution using a scatter plot:

```
(df.assign(bin=np.mean([df['low_bin'], df['high_bin']], axis=0))
   .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(tmp['frequency'])]
   .assign(Y=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
   .plot.scatter(x='bin', y='Y', s=600)
)
```

It works by getting the average of low/high as X value, then repeating the rows as many times as the "frequency" value, and incrementing the count with a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

Output:

[image]